# hSeek and SeekFromEnd in Haskell

Tags: haskell, mmap

I'm looking to retrieve just the last line of a file quickly in Haskell---starting from the end, not the beginning---and having some difficulties using hSeek correctly.

It seems the `SeekFromEnd N` behaves differently than finding the length of the file `sz`, and using `AbsoluteSeek` to go `(sz - N)` bytes.

```
outh <- openFile "test.csv" ReadMode

λ> hIsSeekable outh
True

λ> hFileSize outh
81619956
λ> hSeek outh AbsoluteSeek 1000
λ> hTell outh
1000

λ> hSeek outh SeekFromEnd 1000
λ> hTell outh
81620956

λ> hSeek outh AbsoluteSeek 0
λ> hGetLine outh
"here's my data"

λ> hSeek outh SeekFromEnd 10000
-*** Exception: test.csv: hGetLine: end of file
```

Hm, that's weird.

So, I made a function that does this with absolute instead:

```
λ> hSeek outh SeekFromEnd 100000
λ> hTell outh
81719956

fromEnd outh = do
  sz <- hFileSize outh
  hSeek outh AbsoluteSeek (sz - 100000)

λ> fromEnd outh

λ> hTell outh
81519956
```

So output-wise, they have different answers which is weird.  Additionally, I can now also use hGetLine, which SeekFromEnd failed on:

```
λ> hGetLine outh
"partial output"
λ> hGetLine outh
"full output, lots of fields, partial output"
```

Not clear to me what's going on here.  Why does my fromEnd behave differently than SeekFromEnd in permitting hGetLine?

Part II of the question: what /would/ be the right strategy for starting at the end of the file and seeking backwards to the first newline (the first \n after the EOF newline)?

In this question, I'm looking specifically for an answer using SeekFromEnd.

Comment: It seems that `hSeek outh SeekFromEnd 1000` moved to 1000 bytes _after_ the end! That should not happen. ["It is not possible to set a negative I/O position, or for a physical file, an I/O position beyond the current end-of-file."](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hSeek) Now I'm confused as well. Anyway, I think you should use offset -1000.

Comment: Ah, I should have used the ancient science of subtraction.  Thanks, @chi, didn't even notice that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell Read Last Line with a Lazy mmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656678/haskell-read-last-line-with-a-lazy-mmap)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate of your newer question. My answer there answers your questions here to. I wish I had seen this question first and put my answer here instead. Oh well. :)

Comment: Thank you as always for your help @Alec.  Any chance you can rather move that answer here, and we keep that thread open for an answer using mmap, where this one uses seek?  I'd like to learn both IO patterns.

Comment: @Mittenchops Fair point, I guess.

Comment: Thanks again, @Alec.  I'll learn Haskell yet...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offset to `SeekFromEnd` is expected to be negative.

As for getting the last line of a file, we come across the annoyance that we have to scan each character from the end, one by one, every time resetting the position. That said, we *can* do it - we just keep moving back until we encounter the first `\n` character.

```
import System.IO

-- | Given a file handle, find the last line. There are no guarantees as to the 
-- position of the handle after this call, and it is expected that the given
-- handle is seekable.
hGetLastLine :: Handle -> IO String
hGetLastLine hdl = go "" (negate 1)
  where
  go s i = do
    hSeek hdl SeekFromEnd i
    c <- hGetChar hdl
    if c == '\n'
      then pure s
      else go (c:s) (i-1)
```

You may want to add an off by one here, as most files generally end in an `\n` (and that empty line is probably not what you want)

Comment: This works super quickly on my machine.  I had to change 
hGetLastLine hdl = go "" (negate 2)
To do exactly what you said, with the last character being \n.  I guess on windows it would need to be 3 because of \r\n...