# Haskell Read Last Line with a Lazy mmap

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, mmap

I want to read the last line of my file and make sure it has the same number of fields as my first---I don't care about anything in the middle.  I'm using mmap because it's fast for random access on large files, but am encountering problems not understanding Haskell or laziness.

```
λ> import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB
λ> import System.IO.MMap
λ> outh <- mmapFileByteStringLazy fname Nothing 
λ> LB.length outh
87094896
λ> LB.takeWhile (`notElem` "\n") outh
"\"Field1\",\"Field2\",
```

Great.

From [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.9.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html#v:takeWhileR), I know that

> takeWhileR p xs is equivalent to reverse (takeWhileL p (reverse
>   xs)).

So let's make this.  That is, let's get the last line by reversing my lazy bytestring, taking while not "\n" just as before, then unreversing it.  Laziness makes me think the compiler will let me do this easily.

So trying this out:

```
LB.reverse (LB.takeWhile (`notElem` "\n") (LB.reverse outh))
```

What I expect to see is:

```
"\"val1\",\"val2\",
```

Instead, this crashes my session.

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Questions:

1. What am I doing wrong with laziness, or bytestrings, or the mmap library, or Haskell?
2. How can I get this line correctly and with memory efficiency?  (The answer possibly using foreign pointers instead of lazy bytestrings?)

For other readers, if you're looking to get the last line, you may find a very fast and suitable method described in the answer here: [hSeek and SeekFromEnd in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654849/hseek-and-seekfromend-in-haskell)

In this thread, I'm looking specifically for a solution using mmap.

Comment: The [`readFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:readFile) function returns a lazily evaluated string, meaning you can use it to process, say, multiple GB sized files without running out of memory (as explained [here](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html#io.lazy)). Considering that, what do you see wrong in a simple combination of `readFile`, [`lines`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lines), and [`last`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:last)?

Comment: Jeez, segfaults shouldn't happen in pure Haskell! Suspect it's a bug in `mmap`.

Comment: @MarcusViníciusMonteiro, I don't know if I did this correctly, but `λ> (last . lines) <$> readFile fname` gives me `"\"val1\",\"val2\",` correctly. (It's just kind of slow on account of the large file.)

Comment: @Mittenchops does it work in a file with size larger than your RAM? I don't have a file large enough to test it.

Comment: @MarcusViníciusMonteiro I don't think it's too big. The file I'm working on is about 70MB on an 8GB RAM machine.  I have a lot of browser tabs open and all, but not /that/ many?

Comment: @Mittenchops Updated the answer for something using `mmap`. This was a cool problem. Having found the `bytestring-mmap` package, I reckon I will reach again for it next time I am playing with very large files in Haskell. Thanks for the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer the use of [`bytestring-mmap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-mmap-0.2.2) made by the same author as `bytestring`. In either case, all you need is

```
import System.IO.Posix.MMap (unsafeMMapFile)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS

main = do
   -- can be swapped out for `mmapFileByteString` from `mmap`
  bs <- unsafeMMapFile "file.txt"

  let (firstLine, _) = BS.break (== '\n') bs
      (_, lastLine) = BS.breakEnd (== '\n') bs

  putStrLn $ "First line: " ++ BS.unpack firstLine
  putStrLn $ "Last line: " ++ BS.unpack lastLine
```

This runs instantly too, with no extra allocations. As before, there is the caveat that many files end in newlines, so one may want to have `BS.breakEnd (== '\n') (init bs)` to ignore the last `\n` character.

Also, I would not recommend reversing the bytestring - that will require at least some allocations, which are in this case completely avoidable. Even if you use a lazy bytestring, you still pay the cost of going through all the chunks of the bytestring (which hopefully shouldn't even have been constructed at this point). That said, your reversing code *should* work. I reckon something is off with `mmap` (probably the package as the doing the same thing with a strict bytestring works just fine).

#### Previous answer, from before OP's edit

I'm not sure what the problem is with the functions in [`System.IO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/System-IO.html). The following runs instantly on my laptop, file `file.txt` being almost 4GB. It isn't elegant, but it is certainly efficient.

```
import System.IO

hGetLastLine :: Handle -> IO String
hGetLastLine hdl = go "" (negate 1)
  where
  go s i = do
    hSeek hdl SeekFromEnd i
    c <- hGetChar hdl
    if c == '\n'
      then pure s
      else go (c:s) (i-1)


main = do
  handle <- openFile "file.txt" ReadMode

  firstLine <- hGetLine handle
  putStrLn $ "First line: " ++ firstLine

  lastLine <- hGetLastLine handle
  putStrLn $ "Last line: " ++ lastLine
```